BrokenPipeError during multithreading AI training with SubprocVecEnv
I'm working on training a reinforcement learning agent to play super mario bros using SubprocVecEnv to parallelize environments and speed up the process. However, I encounter a BrokenPipeError when running the training code, that evolves to an EOFError.
I use the following libraries:
gym-super-mario-bros 7.4.0
nes-py 8.2.1
opencv-python 4.10.0
gym 0.26.2
I've tried using DummyVecEnv instead but it didn't work and would only delay the training time. If anyone has any insight on how to deal with this, will be much appreciated.
Sorry for my bad English, here is the code:
import gym_super_mario_bros
from nes_py.wrappers import JoypadSpace
from gym_super_mario_bros.actions import RIGHT_ONLY
import time
from Wrappers import nosso_wrapper


from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import SubprocVecEnv
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.callbacks import CheckpointCallback
##
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)
##

def cria_env(nome_env):
    def _init():
        env = gym_super_mario_bros.make(nome_env)
        env = JoypadSpace(env, RIGHT_ONLY)
        env = nosso_wrapper(env)
        return env
    return _init


threads_cpu = 8
env = SubprocVecEnv([cria_env(nome_env='SuperMarioBros-1-1-v0') for i in range(threads_cpu)])



checkpoint_callback = CheckpointCallback(save_freq=6250, save_path='C:\\Users\\Caleb\\Downloads\\Modelos_Salvos_IA', name_prefix='n1024b64l3')

modelo = PPO(policy='CnnPolicy', env=env, gamma=0.99, n_steps=1024, batch_size=64, learning_rate=0.0003, vf_coef=0.5, ent_coef=0.01, verbose=1)

inicio = time.time()
modelo.learn(total_timesteps=10000000, log_interval=10, callback=checkpoint_callback)

fim = time.time()
print('Tempo total do treinamento em horas:', (fim-inicio)/3600)```


And here is the error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BrokenPipeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\envs\MarioIA\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py in _recv_bytes(self, maxsize)
    311                     finally:
--> 312                         nread, err = ov.GetOverlappedResult(True)
    313                         if err == 0:

BrokenPipeError: [WinError 109] O pipe foi finalizado

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18092\1810071706.py in <module>
     33 
     34 inicio = time.time()
---> 35 modelo.learn(total_timesteps=10000000, log_interval=10, callback=checkpoint_callback)
     36 
     37 fim = time.time()

~\anaconda3\envs\MarioIA\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\ppo\ppo.py in learn(self, total_timesteps, callback, log_interval, tb_log_name, reset_num_timesteps, progress_bar)
    312             tb_log_name=tb_log_name,
    313             reset_num_timesteps=reset_num_timesteps,
--> 314             progress_bar=progress_bar,
    315         )

~\anaconda3\envs\MarioIA\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\on_policy_algorithm.py in learn(self, total_timesteps, callback, log_interval, tb_log_name, reset_num_timesteps, progress_bar)
    249             reset_num_timesteps,
    250             tb_log_name,
--> 251             progress_bar,
    252         )
    253 

~\anaconda3\envs\MarioIA\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\base_class.py in _setup_learn(self, total_timesteps, callback, reset_num_timesteps, tb_log_name, progress_bar)
    422             assert self.env is not None
    423             # pytype: disable=annotation-type-mismatch
--> 424             self._last_obs = self.env.reset()  # type: ignore[assignment]
    425             # pytype: enable=annotation-type-mismatch
    426             self._last_episode_starts = np.ones((self.env.num_envs,), dtype=bool)

~\anaconda3\envs\MarioIA\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\vec_env\vec_transpose.py in reset(self)
    108         Reset all environments
    109         """
--> 110         return self.transpose_observations(self.venv.reset())
    111 
    112     def close(self) -> None:

~\anaconda3\envs\MarioIA\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\vec_env\subproc_vec_env.py in reset(self)
    136         for env_idx, remote in enumerate(self.remotes):
    137             remote.send(("reset", self._seeds[env_idx]))
--> 138         results = [remote.recv() for remote in self.remotes]
    139         obs, self.reset_infos = zip(*results)
    140         # Seeds are only used once

~\anaconda3\envs\MarioIA\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\vec_env\subproc_vec_env.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    136         for env_idx, remote in enumerate(self.remotes):
    137             remote.send(("reset", self._seeds[env_idx]))
--> 138         results = [remote.recv() for remote in self.remotes]
    139         obs, self.reset_infos = zip(*results)
    140         # Seeds are only used once

~\anaconda3\envs\MarioIA\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py in recv(self)
    248         self._check_closed()
    249         self._check_readable()
--> 250         buf = self._recv_bytes()
    251         return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
    252 

~\anaconda3\envs\MarioIA\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py in _recv_bytes(self, maxsize)
    319                 except OSError as e:
    320                     if e.winerror == _winapi.ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE:
--> 321                         raise EOFError
    322                     else:
    323                         raise

EOFError: 

